# How to Validate this Statistical Model?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a statistical model and I want to test out how well it works.  I have N data points, and I want to see if they come from a specific distribution that my model predicts.  Each distribution is binomial, but the parameters are different for each point.  I'd like to use some sort of statistical test where the null hypothesis is that all N data points come from their corresponding distributions.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach if you have a generative model for your parameters: Compute the likelihood for your data points (however you want, e.g. maximizing over the parameters), and then generate synthetic data according to your model (using the generative model on parameters) where the synthetic data sets' size is the same as your original data, and compute the likelihood for each such set of synthetic data, using the same procedure you used to compute likelihood for your original data. Then define the $p$-value to be the percentage of synthetic data sets that gave lower likelihood than your original data set.